# The height of the code-mirror block are not the same in Chrome and Safari

Tags: css, cross-browser, flexbox, height, codemirror

I want to make a layout that satisfies the following conditions:

1) it has a block on the top whose `height` is up to its content

2) below it has a `code-mirror` and a block side by side, which fill in **exactly** the rest of the page in terms of `height`.

I have made a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/p8fmdigoMUYgnk9zclYN?p=preview) here. The problem is it works well in `Chrome 57.0.2987.133`, whereas it does NOT work well in `Safari 10.1`: the `height` of the `code-mirror` is NOT enough; it shows only `76` lines of the code rather than the correct `80` lines.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
<style>
    .rb {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .rb .container {
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100% /* new */
    }
    .rb .first-row {
        border: 1px solid black;
        /*flex: 0 0 60px;*/
    }
    .rb .CodeMirror {
        flex: 1;
        height: auto;
    }
    .rb .flex-preview {
        flex: 1;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>

<div class="rb">
    <div class="first-row">
        1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <textarea ng-model="body" ui-codemirror="option"></textarea>
        <div class="flex-preview">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router', 'ui.codemirror']);
    app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('global', {
              templateUrl: 'template.html'
            })
    }]);
    app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state) {
      $scope.option = { mode: 'text/html', lineNumbers: true, matchBrackets: true };
      $scope.body = ""
      for (var i = 1; i <= 79; i++) 
          $scope.body = $scope.body + "a\n";
      $state.go('global')
    }])

  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: an asterisk css (*) selects all elements (or elements of a selected type depending on how you code it) e.g. div *{ css here}  see https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_all.asp

Comment: did you make your rb into an id? That may help  try this https://run.plnkr.co/q1bvFaeFVsbBviQs/

Comment: the plunker i posted above works in windows safari.. how did you get on

Comment: it says "not found"

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/8XYdWN3tRXjIfUWTCSRV?p=preview i forked yours though the other link worked

Comment: sorry... p8xxxxxx is my initial plunker...

Comment: I think you posted the wrong link...

Comment: the link 8X... still shows 76 lines in Safari mac

Comment: I did scroll down fully... I need to see a working example to accept an answer or upvote a comment... Again, it is a tough question, thanks for your help...

Comment: I just saw you edited your answer, [plnkr.co/edit/8XYdWN3tRXjIfUWTCSRV?p=preview](https://plnkr.co/edit/8XYdWN3tRXjIfUWTCSRV?p=preview) does work in Safari in Windows as you show, but it does not work in Safari Mac. I just upvoted your answer...

Comment: Just saw your comment on the app. Thanks for that. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

According to http://www.caniuse.com, there are few [known issues with Safari re vh](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units):

```
Safari & iOS Safari (both 6 and 7) does not support viewport units 
for border widths, column gaps, transform values, box shadows or in calc().

iOS 7 Safari sets viewport unit values to 0 if the page has been left 
and is returned to after 60 seconds.

iOS 7 Safari recalculates widths set in vh as vw, and heights set in vw
as vh, when orientation changes.

vh on iOS is reported to include the height of the bottom toolbar in the
height calculation, and the width of the sidebar (bookmarks) in the vw 
width calculation.
```

As you have set border-widths in the code posted, the use of vertical height (vh) as a measurement unit is going to pose a problem for you.

There are a few workarounds I suppose, you could use percentage, adjust the vh if safari using browser detection (modernizer?) or you could perhaps add a margin or padding? Just some thoughts off the top of my head. Good luck.

Hope this helps

EDIT: Your issue may lie with the use of flex which unfortunately has [issues in Safari](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=137730) which is marked as fixed because it used to appear in Chrome also, but was fixed in Chrome 51. It still occurs in Safari according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

```
In Safari, the height of (non flex) children are not recognized in percentages. 
However other browsers recognize and scale the children based on percentage heights. (See bug) 
The bug also appeared in Chrome but was fixed in Chrome 51
```

The indication that non-flex children is NOT measured in % would suggest that vh may be used instead (which leads back to my earlier answer).

On the upside, it's not just you that's experiencing the issue! It's a known bug that should be fixed in a future release. Every cloud has a silver lining.. :)

[image: plunker in windows safari]

EDIT #2

Another issue with Safari (iOS) is that it doesn't support min-width (actually only on table elements on second look) in CSS. Your externally linked in stylesheets may be using min-width so this may also have an effect on the output. It is recorded as [happening in iOS 5.1](http://www.caniuse.com/#feat=minmaxwh) but it is unclear whether it was fixed in later versions.

Comment: @SoftTimur sorry the other answer confused me then.. I'll have a good look at the plunkr, but leave the issues there, they may help another user

Comment: @SoftTimur on my chrome browser (the latest one), only 80 lines are showing? Has the code been adjusted since posting? I thought there were 81?

Comment: I don't think it has been adjusted, but for me it is 80 as well now... I will modify the OP...

Comment: @SoftTimur comment back in the first-row flex css? does that work? i haven't tried it (pc user!)

Comment: @SoftTimur Consider even making your rb class into an id, so that way the classes would inherit the display:flex; css

Comment: "comment back in the first-row flex css" ==> actually, I want to height of first-row to be flexible (up to the height of the content, up to the width of the browser)... that indeed makes things difficult... For "a * css", I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9m0FPNtJW41AnQyFQW1i?p=preview) where `rb` is an id, it has the same problem in safari

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#concept-column.   Column is still interpreted as a table element even without the table tag in HTML5, you are displaying as column within flex. This could potentially be the problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
.rb .container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto /* new */
}
```

Try using height as 'auto'.

Answer (score 3):

You're setting the height of the `code-mirror` container (`.rb`) using `height: 100%`. But you don't have any height specified on the parent container.

When you use percentage heights, some browsers still require you to define a height on the parent (using the `height` property). That's been the traditional implementation of the [spec language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276), although not all browsers adhere to that interpretation anymore.

However, if you're going to use `height: 100%` on an element, and you want to ensure cross-browser support, make sure the parent container has a defined height. If the parent also uses a percentage height, then its parent must also have a  defined height.

Alternatively, just use `height: 100vh` on `.rb` and be done with it.

Then your `flex: 1` on `.container` will work to consume available height.

More information and other solutions here:

- [Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height of flex parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276)
- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

Comment: Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NZT47lFUBnkCPLA2xnuW?p=preview) with `height: 100vh`. In Safari, it stills shows only `76` lines of the code rather than the correct `81` lines. Could you provide a working plunker?

Comment: If you could post enough code in your question to reproduce the problem, we can help you more specifically.